# Find all continuous repeating characters using a simpler solution or preferably a regex

Tags: python-2.7

I want to find a simpler solution to capturing all continuous repeating characters in a string. I was trying a regex approach earlier but I could not even get close.

This is how I could fetch the continuous repeating characters using a for loop but it would be better if I could solve it in fewer lines using some inbuilt or library functions.

```
strin="aaabbcccccddd"
prevChar=strin[0]
contin=[]
currSt=""
for i in strin:
    if i==prevChar:
        currSt=currSt+i
    else:
        contin.append(currSt)
        prevChar=i
        currSt=""
        currSt+=prevChar
if currSt:
    contin.append(currSt)
print contin
```

O/P :`['aaa', 'bb', 'ccccc', 'ddd']`

I am using python-2.7. Any help is appreciated.

**Update :**

I would be adding this as a feature in a Machine Learning algorithm where the corpus can be huge. So an efficient solution consuming less time would be preferable. Also I would want characters that repeat, not singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you only want characters that repeat, not singletons.

This regex will match any character that is followed by at least one of
the same character:

```
re.findall(r'((.)\2+)', strin)
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
[('aaa', 'a'), ('bb', 'b'), ('ccccc', 'c'), ('ddd', 'd')]
```

So we need to clean it up. Complete solution:

```
[t[0] for t in re.findall(r'((.)\2+)', strin)]
```

Output:

```
['aaa', 'bb', 'ccccc', 'ddd']
```

Comment: That rocks. It works on both the cases .`"aaabbcccccdddaaa"`

Comment: Also that addition to my question where I would want characters that repeat, not singletons was a good help .

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> strin="aaabbcccccddd"
>>> set([item * list(strin).count(item) for item in list(strin)])
set(['ccccc', 'aaa', 'bb', 'ddd'])
```

Sorted `list` result,

```
>>> sorted(set([item * list(strin).count(item) for item in list(strin)]))
['aaa', 'bb', 'ccccc', 'ddd']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in your case if my input is `strin="aaabbcccccdddaaa"` then I get an output as `set(['aaaaaa', 'ccccc', 'bb', 'ddd'])` or `['aaaaaa', 'bb', 'ccccc', 'ddd']` where as I would want it to be `['aaa', 'bb', 'ccccc', 'ddd','aaa']`.